# How to get the correct index after async call from Parse.com in Javascript/AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, parse-platform

One of the keys in my Object-A Class is a pointer to another object-b, hence when I get an array of Object-As, I need to fetch the object-b (async) for each Object-A:

```
$scope.aList = queryResults;
for (var i = 0; i < queryResults.length; i++){ 
    getObject($scope.aList[i].pointerToB).then(function(objectB){
          $scope.aList[i].title = objectB.title;
    });
}

getObject: function(obj){
        return [$q.when(obj.fetch())];
},
```

even though all the objects are fetched successfully but they are all put in the wrong indexing, as you can see, the 'i' in $scope.aList[i].title is not in sync with the counter.

How can I correctly link the fetched object-b back to the original Object-A it belongs to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even better... when you query for ObjectA class, use the `include` method so you don't need to fetch ObjectB objects embedded inside.

```
var query = new Parse.Query("ObjectA");
query.include("column-name-which-points-to-ObjectB");
query.find().then(function(results) {
  // ObjectB objects are fully fetched too.
});
```